# How to clear session whenever close the browser?

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net

```
var clicked = false;

function CheckBrowser() {
   // debugger;
    if (clicked == false) {
                 //Browser closed   
    } else {
        //redirected
        clicked = false;
           }
}
function bodyUnload() {
    if (clicked == false)//browser is closed  
    {
        var request = GetRequest();

        //       request.open("GET", "../../LogOut.aspx", true);
        request.open("GET", "LogOut.aspx", true);

        request.send();
    }
}

function GetRequest() {
    var xmlHttp = null;
    try {
        // Firefox, Opera 8.0+, Safari
        xmlHttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    catch (e) {
        //Internet Explorer
        try {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
        }
        catch (e) {
            xmlHttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
    }
    return xmlHttp;
}
```

this is my javascript code.
I want to clear session when browser closed but its not working?
I am sending request to this on `logout.aspx` but it doesn't work.

Comment: All `Sessions`are destroyed automatically, when you close browser

Comment: @TirthPatel, OP is talking about server side sessions..

Comment: Why are you worried about this. Garbage collection on your server will do this. Do you have memory issues on your server?

Comment: You have to use window.onbeforeunload this event to call your method

Comment: It has been a very, very long time since I last worked on web application, but back then there was no way to know if the browser is being closed or the user just navigates to a different page. If there is a way to do it now, what's stopping you from sending a simple Ajax request to the server and do whatever you want there?

Comment: Do you really want to clear the session on the server, or do you want to disconnect the browser from the session (Session is lost when the browser is opened again)? If it is the latter, you could set the expiry date of the session cookie in the past, that way the session cookie is deleted as soon as the browser is closed, and the user has 'lost' the session. It will still be in memory on the server until the session itself expires though.